# pgfplots: How to control and align legend items precisely above each other?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, legend, tikz-graphdrawing

The user [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480284/78784) has posted a really nice approach of adding legend items into one single box below a multigraph diagram by placing them inside a `\node`.

Based on this initial situation I have tried to separate the legend items into three rows above each other, but the result is missleading.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plots]
 \begin{axis}[
             axis y line*                                = left,
             legend to name                              = legA,
             legend style                                = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm},
                 },
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (0,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
             \legend{Graph 1, Graph 2, Graph 3};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legB,
             legend style                                = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm},
             },
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.15) (1,0.15)};
             \legend{Graphinggraph 4, Graphinggraph 5, Graphinggraph 6};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legC,
             legend style                                = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm},
             },
             ]%
             \pgfplotsset%
                 {%
                 every outer y axis line/.style          = {xshift=2cm},
                 every tick/.style                       = {xshift=2cm},
                 every y tick label/.style               = {xshift=2cm},
                 }%
             \addplot coordinates {(0.5,0) (0.5,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.7,0) (0.7,1)};
             \legend{Graphgraph 7, Graphgraph 8, Graphgraph 9};
 \end{axis}%
\end{scope}
\node[below=3.5em of plots.south] (legA) {\ref{legA}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legA] (legB) {\ref{legB}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legB] (legC) {\ref{legC}};
\draw (legA.north west) rectangle (legC.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see,

- the border does not fit with the outer dimension of the legend items,
- the legend items are not precisely aligned below each other.

So my questions are: How to solve this and make it look nice?

Comment: You could create the legend using a tabular.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture for tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a large enough `text width` to all of these legends. True, this is not entirely automatic (Ti*k*Z does understand something like `width("blablabla")` but writing a fully automatic solution may be an overkill here), but seems to be reasonably simple to me.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{superb legend/.style={legend style                                = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm,
                 text width=7em},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm,
                  text width=7em},
                 }}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plots]
 \begin{axis}[
             axis y line*                                = left,
             legend to name                              = legA,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (0,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
             \legend{Graph 1, Graph 2, Graph 3};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legB,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.15) (1,0.15)};
             \legend{Graphinggraph~4, Graphinggraph~5, Graphinggraph~6};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legC,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \pgfplotsset%
                 {%
                 every outer y axis line/.style          = {xshift=2cm},
                 every tick/.style                       = {xshift=2cm},
                 every y tick label/.style               = {xshift=2cm},
                 }%
             \addplot coordinates {(0.5,0) (0.5,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.7,0) (0.7,1)};
             \legend{Graphgraph 7, Graphgraph 8, Graphgraph 9};
 \end{axis}%
\end{scope}
\node[below=3.5em of plots.south] (legA) {\ref{legA}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legA] (legB) {\ref{legB}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legB] (legC) {\ref{legC}};
\draw (legA.north west) rectangle (legC.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Just to clarify: yes, I know that there exist `cycle list`s which allow one to make all plot styles different, but I am not sure if this is desired here.)

**EDIT**: Increased the `text width`, big thanks to quark67!

Comment: Could I suggest you to use `7.5em` instead of `6.5em` in the `every even column` and `every odd column` in purpose to avoid the drop figures in `Graphinggraph 4`, `Graphinggraph 5`, `Graphinggraph 6` text in the legend box? But perhaps there exist a better workaround, because with my suggestion, the legend box isn't centered.

Comment: @quark67 Thanks a lot!

Comment: @marmot: Thank you so much for your great help!! I really appreciate your fantastic expertise! Maybe you also have an idea on how to align the plot width to the same width as the legend? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480910