# pgfplots: How to align plot width to same width as legend when compiling external?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, width, legend, adjustwidth

The user [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480917/78784) has posted a nice approach on how to adjust the plot width to the legend width.

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{superb legend/.style={legend style          = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm,
                 text width=7em},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm,
                  text width=7em},
                 }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\ifdefined\mylegendwidth
\ifdim\mylegendwidth<0pt
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{abs(\mylegendwidth)}
\def\mylegendwidth{\mywidth pt}
\fi
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mylegendwidth{10cm}
\fi
\pgfplotsset{width=\mylegendwidth}

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plots]
 \begin{axis}[
             axis y line*                                = left,
             legend to name                              = legA,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (0,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
             \legend{Graph 1, Graph 2, Graph 3};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legB,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.15) (1,0.15)};
             \legend{Graphinggraph~4, Graphinggraph~5, Graphinggraph~6};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legC,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \pgfplotsset%
                 {%
                 every outer y axis line/.style          = {xshift=2cm},
                 every tick/.style                       = {xshift=2cm},
                 every y tick label/.style               = {xshift=2cm},
                 }%
             \addplot coordinates {(0.5,0) (0.5,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.7,0) (0.7,1)};
             \legend{Graphgraph 7, Graphgraph 8, Graphgraph 9};
 \path (current axis.west) coordinate (aux1)  ([xshift=2cm]current axis.east)
  coordinate (aux2);
 \end{axis}%
\end{scope}

\node[anchor=north west] at ([yshift=-3.5em]plots.south-|aux1) (legA) {\ref{legA}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legA] (legB) {\ref{legB}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legB] (legC) {\ref{legC}};
\draw let \p1=($(legC.east)-(legA.west)$),\p2=($(aux2)-(aux1)$) in
[/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{\mylegendwidth+\x1-\x2}%
\xdef\mylegendwidth{\mywidth pt}]
 (legA.north west) rectangle (legC.south east);

\makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mylegendwidth{\mylegendwidth}\relax}
\makeatother

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

Unfortunately when displaying huge amounts of data points, LaTeX will complain about exceeded memory. To avoid this behavior [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7965/78784) has posted an approach on how to externalize compiling the plots:

Mr. Joseph Wright wrote:

- Adding

  ```
  \usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
  \tikzexternalize
  ```

  to the preamble
- and typing

  ```
  pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>
  ```

  into the shell should work.

---

However, after extending the code with this and recompiling, the legend won't match with the plot anymore:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

---

Is there an option available to avoid this behavior and get the plot matching again?

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE) including the edits based on Joseph Wright:**

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
% -------------------------------------------------
% This is new:
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot, statistics, external}
\tikzexternalize
% -------------------------------------------------
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, scale only axis}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{superb legend/.style={legend style          = {draw=none,
                 legend columns                          = 3,
                 /tikz/every even column/.append style   = {column sep=0.5cm,
                 text width=7em},
                 /tikz/every odd column/.append style    = {column sep=0.15cm,
                  text width=7em},
                 }}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ifdefined\mylegendwidth
\ifdim\mylegendwidth<0pt
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{abs(\mylegendwidth)}
\def\mylegendwidth{\mywidth pt}
\fi
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mylegendwidth{10cm}
\fi
\pgfplotsset{width=\mylegendwidth}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plots]
 \begin{axis}[
             axis y line*                                = left,
             legend to name                              = legA,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(1,0) (0,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,1)};
             \legend{Graph 1, Graph 2, Graph 3};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legB,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (1,0)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.5) (1,0.5)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0,0.15) (1,0.15)};
             \legend{Graphinggraph~4, Graphinggraph~5, Graphinggraph~6};
 \end{axis}%
 %
 \begin{axis}[
             axis x line                                 = none,
             axis y line*                                = right,
             legend to name                              = legC,
             superb legend
             ]%
             \pgfplotsset%
                 {%
                 every outer y axis line/.style          = {xshift=2cm},
                 every tick/.style                       = {xshift=2cm},
                 every y tick label/.style               = {xshift=2cm},
                 }%
             \addplot coordinates {(0.5,0) (0.5,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.6,0) (0.6,1)};
             \addplot coordinates {(0.7,0) (0.7,1)};
             \legend{Graphgraph 7, Graphgraph 8, Graphgraph 9};
 \path (current axis.west) coordinate (aux1)  ([xshift=2cm]current axis.east)
  coordinate (aux2);
 \end{axis}%
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=north west] at ([yshift=-3.5em]plots.south-|aux1) (legA) {\ref{legA}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legA] (legB) {\ref{legB}};
\node[below=-0.5em of legB] (legC) {\ref{legC}};
\draw let \p1=($(legC.east)-(legA.west)$),\p2=($(aux2)-(aux1)$) in
[/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mywidth}{\mylegendwidth+\x1-\x2}%
\xdef\mylegendwidth{\mywidth pt}]
 (legA.north west) rectangle (legC.south east);
\makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mylegendwidth{\mylegendwidth}\relax}
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```